# Using set in c++ standard template library (STL)

Tags: c++, stl, insert, set

Sets are the collection. There is a function in set is`insert()`.

It's return type : it returns the iterator pointing to the inserted element in the collection.

I write a code and its working :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

set<int> s;

s.insert (1);

s.insert (4);

s.insert (2);

s.insert (5);

s.insert (3);

cout << "The elements in set are: ";

for (auto it = s.begin(); it!= s.end (); it++)

cout << *it;

return 0;
}
```

I write another code and it also working:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 
set<int> s;

auto itr=s.insert (s.begin(),5);

itr=s.insert (itr,4);

itr=s.insert (itr,2);

cout << "The elements in set are: ";

for (auto it = s.begin(); it!= s.end (); it++)

cout << *it;

return 0;
}
```

Now i merge the logic of both my previous code but now its not working why? :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

set<int> s;

auto itr=s.insert (1);

s.insert (itr,4);


cout << "The elements in set are: ";

for (auto it = s.begin(); it!= s.end (); it++)

cout << *it;

return 0;
}
```

Output in above code :

```
 
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_set.h:536:7: note: candidate: std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, const value_type&) [with _Key = int; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = int]
       insert(const_iterator __position, const value_type& __x)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_set.h:536:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>, bool>’ to ‘std::set<int>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>}’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_set.h:541:7: note: candidate: std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Key = int; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = int]
       insert(const_iterator __position, value_type&& __x)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_set.h:541:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>, bool>’ to ‘std::set<int>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>}’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_set.h:556:2: note: candidate: template<class _InputIterator> void std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; _Key = int; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]
  insert(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
  ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_set.h:556:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
yo.cpp:14:16: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_InputIterator’ (‘std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>, bool>’ and ‘int’)
 s.insert (itr,4)
                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/set:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/stdc++.h:87,
                 from yo.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_set.h:568:7: note: candidate: void std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::initializer_list<_Tp>) [with _Key = int; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]
       insert(initializer_list<value_type> __l)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_set.h:568:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Comment: When in doubt, check the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) (in particular, check what type each overload returns).

Comment: And an obligatory comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) + [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Your error message has no error message in it. `note` means that it's an addon message to the actual error.

Comment: Why it is not working

Comment: Did you read the [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) provided by @Yksisarvinen ?  What type do you think `itr` has in the non-working example?

Comment: I got your point @Yksisarvinen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the syntax:

```
auto itr = s.insert(5);
```

The return type of `s.insert()` with the parameter `5` gives a type of:

```
std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator, bool>
```

But there's no such known overloaded conversion from that type to `std::set<int>::iterator` in the syntax:

```
itr = s.insert(itr, 4); // error!
_______________^^^_____
```

To solve it, you need to declare `itr` correctly:

```
auto itr = s.insert(s.begin(), 5);
```

Rather than only:

```
auto itr = s.insert(5);
```

In the correct case, the return type of `s.insert()` is `std::set<int>::iterator` which is compatible for the next statements.